# How do I use readline for Discord Bots?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

While trying to make my Discord Bot I ran into yet another problem. I'm trying to have a way to have the owner have the bot say something in the announcement section for me so it doesn't show up as my name.

I've tried the readline interface (though I don't know if I did it correctly) and I've tried to do different ways of making a variable (const, var).

```
if(message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Owner")){
  return message.reply("What would you like to say?")
  const dm = message.content;
  return message.reply("$dm")
```

I want the bot to respond with whatever I say. So, If I put in **The Server Is Going Down Soon!** then the bot should say that back to me (in this case).

Answer (score 0):

When you call `return` you're ending the execution of the function that you're writing.

In this case,

```
if(message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Owner")){
  return message.reply("What would you like to say?") // the current function stops
  const dm = message.content; // this line never executes
  return message.reply("$dm")
```

You will have to wait for the response from the user who I presume is responding to a command of some sort

```
if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Owner")) {
    await message.reply("What would you like to say?"); // Send the request
    // Wait for the person who sent the original message to send another message
    let userMessages = await message.channel
        .awaitMessages(m => m.id === message.member.id, { max: 1 }); 
    let userMessage = userMessages.first()
    // Reply with the message they sent
    return message.member.reply(userMessage.content);
```

Comment: In the Console it says, `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: Well obviously you will have to make your function async then